# Does Codename One's BrowserComponent have a built-in native loading spinner?

Tags: spinner, codenameone

I have discovered that when using the BrowserComponent, when navigating from one section to another on my own website, that spinner appears. I would like to know if it's possible to configure it or remove it directly so that I can place my own on my site.

[image]

I have read about it, and I see that the available information is somewhat outdated, from when the issue was about adding a spinner, but now what I need is to remove it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the Android Browser which isn't as good as the iOS one. It can be disabled with the line:

```
CN.setProperty("WebLoadingHidden", "true");
```

Notice this line only needs to appear once in your app and will apply to all browsers you open from this point on so it's OK to put it in your `init(Object)` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Shai, always prompt and accurate. It has worked perfectly.